# Error creating product after 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3 upgrade

Tags: magento-catalog, magento2.4.3

I've upgraded Magento on my dev. site from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3, which went smoothly, but if I click 'Add Product' I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?))' at line
> 2, query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM
> `mgxv_catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` INNER JOIN
> `mgxv_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = l.parent_id
> WHERE (l.product_id IN(?))

This is from exception.log:

[2021-08-26 08:57:50] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?))' at line 2, query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `mgxv_catalog_product_super_link` AS `l`
INNER JOIN `mgxv_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = l.parent_id WHERE (l.product_id IN(?)) {"report_id":"ec517c5a03ebe3ba0494ab4d33408db992171b57923a4032be36c29afb2bddf6","exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?))' at line 2, query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `mgxv_catalog_product_super_link` AS `l`
INNER JOIN `mgxv_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = l.parent_id WHERE (l.product_id IN(?)) at /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?))' at line 2 at /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []

Is anyone able to advise what might cause this, please?

Comment: mgxv_catalog_product_entity, seems a third party module, try disable the module and/or check the observer

Comment: mgxv is the prefix of each table in our database.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by an Amasty extension, and is now fixed.

Comment: Can you please share the solution